# Select box not showing selected values in angular 10 but showing in angular 8 with same code

Tags: angular, angular10

I have following code in two different applications developed in Angular 8 and 10 and it is not showing selected value in angular 10 app but showing properly in angular 8 app

```
<select [value]="10">
 <ng-container *ngFor="let hour of hours">
  <option [value]="hour">{{hour}}</option>
 </ng-container>
</select>
```

Here hours is an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
I've cross checked this code 
" <select [value]="10">
 <ng-container *ngFor="let hour of hours">
  <option [value]="hour">{{hour}}</option>
 </ng-container>
</select> "

It is working on both Angular 8 as well as on Angular 10. On both of the version by dedault it is showing the first element of array is selected.
```